# How bad it is to use @Resource injection in the production code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I find @RequestMapping is very usable in the controller class. This annotation based controller maps a url to a method instead to a class. Also I dont need to bloat the spring-servlet.xml for handler mapping.

But with this it looks like only @Autowired or @Resource is possible for the dependency injection. Is there any other way?

And how bad its to use @Resource in the production code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not bad at all. Using `@Autowired` / `@Resource` / `@Inject` is a perfectly normal way of specifying injection points.

One drawback of `@Resource` (that has nothing to do with production vs development) is the it relies on strings, which are not checked at compile-time. Instead you can use `@Qualifier` if you need to specify a concrete implementation for injection, rather than an interface.

Comment: @Bozho, don't you think they can have performance implications in environments where new instances are created frequently (such as Google App Engine) ?  I mean, if that annotations are discovered at runtime, I suppose the process can take more time than using a XML file to define, in a declarative way, the relations between the objects.

Comment: @Guido - no, these annotations are scanned only at startup. And it is arguable which takes more time - parsing xml or getting metadata from classes.

Comment: @Guido, just now i read somewhere class level @Resource are scanned at run time where property/method level are scanned at startup time

Comment: @Bozho, i am new to spring, I understand the xml mapping. I have a vague idea of this @autowiring, and @resource after reading on the internet. Can you please tell me what is done in the background like will it scan for bean? will it scan for classes?

Comment: @kalyan - it will first scan for classes starting from the base-package you specify. Then it will parse all annotations it knows (using reflection), and will inject the desired dependencies in their places.

Comment: @Bozho Thanks. The @Qualifier will confirm that the correct bean is injected.